# Micrometer/Prometheus how to get recorded metric

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

I'm currently recording method's execution time using `@Timed(value = "data.processing.time")` annotation, but I also would love to read the method's execution time data and compare it with the method's execution limit that I want to set in my properties and then send the data to prometheus, I would assume that there is a way to get the metrics out of MeterRegistry, but currently can't get how, is there a way to do so?

Currently used dependancies:

```
'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.10.4'
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.5.12'
```

Current usage:

```
    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }



    @Timed(value = "data.processing.time")
    private boolean process(byte[] data, String ti, Integer priority) {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see more of your code, but maybe you could record it as a histogram - like this:

```
methodDuration = Histogram.build()
    .name("data_processing_duration")
    .register(meterRegistry);

Histogram.Timer timer = methodDuration.startTimer();
timer.observeDuration();
```

Comment: Can you please specify in which library this Histogram class is, is it micrometer class?

Also added used dependancies and how I currently use them

Comment: Like counters and gauges, it's part of the prometheus client library; https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#histogram

Comment: thanks a lot! Is it right that you don't have to configure anything extra to ship metrics from prometheus:io java client to actual prometheus server?
And will this metric work correctly with metric from micrometer library?

Comment: No, this is outside of Micrometer. Micrometer just happens to reuse he prometheus java client for certain things but I would not recommend using both, check my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `@Bean` of `TimedAspect`. After that `@Timed` should work depending on the proxy and method visibility. `private` methods do not work with the JDK proxy as far as I know so fisrt try to make it package-private:

```java
@Timed(value = "data.processing.time")
boolean process(byte[] data, String ti, Integer priority) {
    //do something
}
```